# continuous function of product topology with singleton

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Hey I was asked to provide a homeomorphism between $X$ and $X \times \{y\}$ if we have a product topology on $X \times Y$ and $y \in Y$, so I came up with this:

we define $f(x) = (x,y)$ which is obviously bijective mapping from $X$ to $X \times {y}$ and now we have to show it is continuous.
Pick $x \in X$ and pick some open set in $Y$, say $V$ which is open and $f(x) \in V$. We can find $U$ open in $X \times \{y\}$ such that $V = U \cap (X\times \{y\})$. Now using product topology on $X \times Y$ we can find $U_1 \in X$ and  $U_2\in Y$ such that $$f(x) = (x,y) \in U_1 \times U_2 \subset V.$$

So for any element $b \in U_1$ we have $f(b) \in U_1 \times U_2$ and $f(b) \in X \times \{y\}$. So $f(b) \in V \forall b \in U_1$.

Also $f^-1$ is continuous because it is the restriction of projection of $X \times Y$ onto $X$.

Does this prove my claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it more simple by arguing that if $f : X \rightarrow X \times  \{y\}$ def as $f(x) =(x,y)$, it obviously continous because for any open subset $V \subset X \times \{y\}$, by definition of product topology, $V$ must be in form of $U \times \{y\}$ where $U \subset X$ is an open subset of $X$. So $f$ is continous bijective map. Because its an open map then it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: so I do not need all the details? thank you very much

Comment: Yes exactly. Other solution is by def the homeo as projection map $\pi_1 : X \times \{y\} \rightarrow X$. This map is open map, bijective, and continous.

Comment: this one is the inverse of my function, right? thank you

Comment: Exactly. Your welcome.